# Style TabWidget background from styles.xml

Tags: android

I have defined custom style for TabWidget in my styles.xml file, to change all TabWidget backgrounds in my application.

```
<item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/CustomTabWidget</item>
<style name="CustomTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bg</item>
</style>
```

In application background stays the same. Similar definition for custom ListView style works correctly. If I set TabWidget background in layout, it works.

```
<TabWidget
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/tab_bg" />
```

How to make TabWidget background to be set from styles.xml?

Answer (score 2):

Are you putting your `android:tabWidgetStyle` item in a custom theme that you defined in your manifest?

styles.xml:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/LightTabWidget</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:name="yourappname"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/logo"
             android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```